# After installing Windows 10 version 1803 (April 2018 Update), screen freezes

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze, hibernate, windows-10-v1803

I have a strange situation. I had recent fresh install of Windows 10 version 1803 and I also tried to upgrade some of my drivers with new releases from the official website. I always disable Automatic Update and never use them.

I am noticing a strange issue since then. While working sometime on high load, screen stops working. I can move my mouse (movement is visible), I can keep talking to other person on Skype,.. but screen doesn't change at all. I can even open apps using keyboard shortcut. They are opened but not shown on screen

I have physical power button mapped to Hibernate. It works too. When I restore from hibernate, screen start working normally.

I'm unable to diagnose the issue correctly. Turning monitor on/off doesn't fix it, but hibernate does though.

I have tried stress test on CPU, GPU, both of the disks, and nothing happens. But sometime out of nowhere it freezes even if I just open a tab.

How do I diagnose the issue and find the culprit? I really don't want to install Windows once again.

Comment: What GPU do you use ? There may be something related to power management. Try an always on schematic.

Comment: @Overmind Intel UHD 630 + NVIDIA GTX 1060. Always on what?

Comment: What does the eventlog say?

Comment: @LPChip Honestly I don't know what should I be looking for in there

Comment: The very first screen in the eventlog shows all errors warnings info grouped together, then a column of last hour, last day and last 7 days show how often a log entry happened. After the screen has an issue, check in the eventlog under errors and warnings for items that were less than an hour old, and check every single one of them.

Comment: Did you install Windows 10 version 180**9**, or was in 180**3**?

Comment: @Run5k Sorry it was 1803. I made a typo :p

Comment: No worries, it happens to the best of us!  If you don't mind, I am going to adjust the title of your question just a bit in order to clarify it for those having the same problem.

Comment: @Run5k Sure thanks. It's usually `09` or `03`. I think I mixed them :p

Comment: Please do us a favor and check back in with us after you install the new Windows Updates that are being released tomorrow.  That way, we will have confirmation that the Microsoft fixes have alleviated the problem.

Comment: Hello, I'm from Brazil and I have a Dell XPS 8920 that presented exactly the same problem. It was attempted to restore windows through the control panel and it did not work. I reinstalled the operating system completely, and I did not have the problem anymore. Anyway, it's just an account to be documented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many people who have proactively installed Windows 10 version 1803 have reported similar issues.  Microsoft is releasing a fix within the [Patch Tuesday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_Tuesday) update tomorrow (8 May 2018):

> Yesterday, [we reported that several users were experiencing Windows
> 10 intermittently
> freezing](https://www.neowin.net/news/google-chrome-is-freezing-intermittently-with-the-windows-10-april-2018-update)
> after [installing the April 2018
> Update](https://www.neowin.net/news/heres-how-to-install-the-windows-10-april-2018-update-on-day-one)
> while using certain software such as Google Chrome. While an official
> fix is not yet available, it now appears that [Microsoft is aware of
> the
> problem](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/some-devices-may-hang-or-freeze-when-using-certain/612a341b-340a-4ac0-8866-df5346327a52?auth=1)
> and will be releasing a solution on May 8.
>
> The issue in question randomly popped up during normal workflow when
> using Chrome, causing Windows 10 to "freeze" and not respond to any
> keystrokes or mouse clicks. The only workarounds, that myself and
> other people experiencing the problem found, were to either close the
> machine's lid and reopen it, or attempt the Windows key sequence
> (Windows + Ctrl + Shift + B) to wake the screen. While some also
> reported that turning off hardware acceleration in Chrome seemed to
> solve the problem, [the workaround did not work for
> me](https://twitter.com/UsamaJawad96/status/992030057903329281).
>
> Now, Microsoft has officially acknowledged the issue, saying that
> Windows 10 does indeed freeze for some users while using software such
> as Cortana and Chrome. The company has posted the same workarounds
> already discovered by users, but has also noted that it is developing
> a fix "with the goal of including it in the next regular monthly
> update".
>
> The next regular monthly update refers to May 8, which is the Patch
> Tuesday for the current month. While the exact scope and root cause of
> the problem is still unknown, it's good to know that Microsoft is
> actively working on a fix.

Source:  [Microsoft is working on a fix for the Windows 10 freezing issue affecting Chrome](https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-is-working-on-a-fix-for-the-windows-10-freezing-issue-affecting-chrome)

---

#### Update 1

Microsoft's official release notes regarding this patch are as follows:

> **Improvements and fixes**
>
> ---
>
> This update includes quality improvements. No new operating system
> features are being introduced in this update. Key changes include:
>
> - Addresses an issue with the April 2018 Windows Servicing update that causes App-V Scripts (User Scripts) to stop working.
> - **Addresses an issue that may cause some devices to stop responding or working when using applications, such as Cortana or Chrome, after
>   installing the Windows 10 April 2018 Update**.
> - Addresses an issue that prevents certain VPN apps from working on builds of Windows 10, version 1803. These apps were developed using an
>   SDK version that precedes Windows 10, version 1803, and use the public
>   RasSetEntryProperties API.
> - Addresses additional issues with updated time zone information.
> - Addresses an issue that may cause an error when connecting to a Remote Desktop server. For more information, see [CredSSP updates for
>   CVE-2018-0886](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866660).
> - Security updates to Windows Server, Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer, Microsoft scripting engine, Windows app platform and
>   frameworks, Windows kernel, Microsoft Graphics Component, Windows
>   storage and filesystems, HTML help, and Windows Hyper-V.
>
> If you installed earlier updates, only the new fixes in this package
> will be downloaded and installed on your device.
>
> For more information about the resolved security vulnerabilities, see
> the [Security Update
> Guide](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/security-guidance).
>
> **Known issues in this update**
>
> ---
>
> Microsoft is not currently aware of any issues with this update.
>
> **How to get this update**
>
> ---
>
> This update will be downloaded and installed automatically from
> Windows Update. To get the standalone package for this update, go to
> the [Microsoft Update
> Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4103721)
> website.

Source:  [May 8, 2018—KB4103721 (OS Build 17134.48)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4103721/windows-10-update-kb4103721)

---

#### Update 2

Microsoft just released another cumulative update to Windows 10 version 1803 that addresses this issue again, and the official release notes are as follows:

> **Improvements and fixes**
>
> ---
>
> This update includes quality improvements. No new operating system
> features are being introduced in this update. Key changes include:
>
> - Addresses an issue that causes the Video Settings HDR streaming calibration slider to stop working. This is caused by a conflict with the panel brightness intensity settings configured by certain OEMs.
> - Addresses streaming compatibility issues with certain live TV streaming content providers.
> - Addresses an issue where media content previously generated by Media Center doesn't play after installing the Windows 10 April 2018 update.
> - Addresses an issue in which SmartHeap didn't work with UCRT.
> - Addresses performance regression in App-V, which slows many actions in Windows 10.
> - Addresses an issue that causes Appmonitor to stop working at logoff if the Settingstoragepath is set incorrectly.
> - Addresses an issue that causes Appmonitor to stop working at logoff, and user settings are not saved.
> - Addresses an issue where client applications running in a container image don't conform to the dynamic port range.
> - Addresses an issue where the DNS server might stop working when using DNS Query Resolution Policies with a "Not Equal" (NE) condition.
> - Addresses an issue with T1 and T2 custom values after configuring DHCP failover.
> - **Addresses an issue that causes the latest versions of Google Chrome (67.0.3396.79+) to stop working on some devices**.
> - Addresses issues with the Remote Desktop client in which pop-up windows and drop-down menus don't appear and right-clicking doesn't work properly. These issues occur when using remote applications.
> - Addresses an issue that causes a connection failure when a Remote Desktop connection doesn’t read the bypass list for a proxy that has multiple entries.
> - Addresses an issue that may cause Microsoft Edge to stop working when it initializes the download of a font from a malformed (not RFC compliant) URL.
> - Addresses an issue where some users may receive an error when accessing files or running programs from a shared folder using the SMBv1 protocol. The error is "An invalid argument was supplied".
> - Addresses an issue that causes Task Scheduler tasks configured with an S4U logon to fail with the error "ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION/STATUS_NO_TRUST_SAM_ACCOUNT".
> - Addresses a performance issue with Windows Mixed Reality on some laptops with hybrid graphics adapters, such as Surface Book 2.
>
> If you installed earlier updates, only the new fixes in this package
> will be downloaded and installed on your device.
>
> **Known issues in this update**
>
> ---
>
> Microsoft is not currently aware of any issues with this update.
>
> **How to get this update**
>
> ---
>
> This update will be downloaded and installed automatically from
> Windows Update. To get the standalone package for this update, go to
> the [Microsoft Update
> Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4284848)
> website.

Source:  [June 26, 2018—KB4284848 (OS Build 17134.137)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4284848)

Comment: I am so glad I was not the only facing the issue. And I swear I tried lot of Googling. I just couldn't find any information.

Comment: Well, I read and study a of IT industry news, and had seen this reported on several occasions.

Comment: Just a note for future readers, according to MS, installing May 2018 update (KB4103721 https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4103721) is supposed to solve this issue.

Comment: Hey! Isn't it weird they don't use SSL to download these .msu files

Comment: Good point. Has the problem disappeared since you installed the patch?

Comment: Hard to tell. I haven't faced this issue since yesterday. Who knows.. maybe I am lucky so far ;)

Comment: For future googlers:  Installing the patch that "fixes" this causes an equally bad issue for me: https://superuser.com/questions/1325137/fresh-install-of-windows-10-freezing-constantly

Answer (score 0):

There are also reports of Win10 not correctly setting hibernation settings through the UI. You can try the following:

```
 powercfg /h ON
 powercfg /X hibernate-timeout-ac 15
 powercfg /X hibernate-timeout-dc 15
```

Source: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/8ievcu/1803_bug_laptop_hibernation/

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue, even if I have tried the combination **Windows + Ctrl + Shift + B** which makes the system hang completely.

However, I have found a temporary solution to this problem to save your data i.e.  connect to your system through RDP (Remote Desktop), close Chrome and Disconnect.

Again login directly and don't open Chrome till this issue is fixed by either Microsoft or Google.

**Updates**

To fix this issue install this update.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4103721/windows-10-update-kb4103721

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1320385/after-installing-windows-10-version-1803-april-2018-update-screen-freezes/1320781#comment1968373_1320474

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4103721/windows-10-update-kb4103721