# Fresh install of Windows 10, freezing constantly

Tags: windows-10, freeze

I just upgraded my PC from Windows 7 to Windows 10.  I did a fresh install to avoid any issues, but unfortunately it's been nothing but problems.

The PC freezes for about 10 seconds every 10 seconds.  When it freezes, I can move the mouse pointer, but nothing responds, not even ctrl+alt+delete.  After 10 seconds of doing absolutely nothing, it seems all my inputs happen at once.  This happens consistently every time I boot.

The only things I've installed are:

- All the latest drivers
- The latest Windows updates (v1803)

I don't have an anti-virus, firewall, or anything else yet.

Specs:

- Motherboard: Asus Maximus IX Hero
- CPU: Intel i7 7700k
- GPU: Nvidia GTX 980 TI

So it's fairly beefy.  The same hardware just worked fine in Windows 7, so it's not a hardware issue.

One thing I've noticed is that the System process is at 15% (> 100% of one CPU core) at all times.  Based on recommendations here, I ran Process Monitor and discovered the faulty thread is called `ntoskrnl.exe!rtlavlremovenode`.  Unfortunately googling that doesn't produce anything useful.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77977/discussion-on-question-by-blueraja-danny-pflughoeft-fresh-install-of-windows-1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After installing Windows 10 version 1803 (April 2018 Update), screen freezes](https://superuser.com/questions/1320385/after-installing-windows-10-version-1803-april-2018-update-screen-freezes)

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the issue using the [these steps](https://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557), it turns out the freeze occurs entirely in `ntoskrnl.exe` *(with the final call being to `ntoskrnl.exe!CmpRemoveKeyHashFromTableEntry`)*, which means it's a Windows bug.  Sure enough, reinstalling Windows and installing the same drivers, but *not* installing the Windows 10 v1803 update fixed the issue.

So the solution is:  Don't install v1803 of Windows until they fix their stuff.  If you already have, roll-back or reinstall :(

Comment: again, post a picture of WPA.exe or share the trace so that I can ask Microsoft if this is really a kernel issue., your "answer" is a rant, but nothing helpful.

Comment: @magicandre1981: I succinctly provided both the cause and solution; how could you _possibly_ not consider this a valid answer?   I've already reported the issue to Microsoft with a screenshot of the trace, but including it in my answer would just be noise.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - I actually agree with Andre, sharing the data you used to identify the cause of the behavior, would improve your answer.  You are being offered, by somebody who has connections to Microsoft, it seems, to investigate this issue.

Comment: Can you please edit your original question to include the appropriate Windows 10 [version and OS build number](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows-10/release-information)? You responded within the subsequent comments, but that information is crucial to any other community members who read the original query. Beyond that, I normally recommend to everyone I work with that they [defer Feature Updates](https://superuser.com/a/1199780/650163) on their Windows 10 machines. I actually have mine configured for `Semi-Annual Channel` with an extra 30-day delay, and I *never* have any problems.

Comment: @Ramhound: Unfortunately it seems the screenshot was lost in the reinstall.  It should still exist within the 'Windows 10 Feedback app' for Microsoft, but it seems they don't let me access the attachments for my feedback, so I can't repost it here.

Comment: no, you provided a rant about Microsoft and Windows but nothing helpful. Where is the ETL file that I can look at?

Comment: I checked my Win10 1803 and don't see the call. cmp means registry, so a program does heavy registry calls which leads to system usage. Use ProcMon to see which process accesses wich key very often

Comment: @magicandre1981, it's very strange to me that you kept calling this a "rant".  Sure, it could have been made better with more info; but as is, it provides a useful workaround (a.k.a. solution a.k.a. answer).  And, it turned out that this was caused by Microsoft, as acknowledged by Microsoft: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/some-devices-may-hang-or-freeze-when-using-certain/612a341b-340a-4ac0-8866-df5346327a52?auth=1