# Screen freezes for a second every few seconds

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, windows-10-v1803

I've been having problems with computer rebooting so I uninstalled my graphics drivers and reinstalled the latest ones (even though I already had the latest ones).

Since the reinstall my computer freezes for one second every few seconds if I move the mouse. This only happens when I move the mouse, if I just scroll or use my keyboard it doesn't freeze.

Also, this only happens if my TV is connected to HDMI and the TV is turned off. It doesn't happen if the TV is turned on.

Relevant details:
Windows 10 Pro x64 Version 1803
OS Build 17134.48
GPU: AMD RX 470
GPU Driver version: 18.5.1

Displays setup:
DVI 1: Monitor 1
DVI 2: Monitor 2 via digital DVI to VGA adapter
HDMI: TV  (one suspect is the cable, it's a 5 meter cable, but why would it only have issues while the TV is off?)

I tried changing the refresh rates but that doesn't seem to have any effect.
My current workaround is to have the TV unplugged when I'm not using it, but that's very inconvenient since I use my PC remotely often.

I'm out of ideas.

The suggested duplicate seems to be a different issue. Also, I remember a few months ago I tried installing amd drivers on my mother's laptop and had the same issue. She has an AMD APU, and no external monitors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After installing Windows 10 version 1803 (April 2018 Update), screen freezes](https://superuser.com/questions/1320385/after-installing-windows-10-version-1803-april-2018-update-screen-freezes)

Comment: Based upon what you described, it is almost certainly related to the Windows 10 version 1803 update.  The first thing I would do is try the `Check for updates` feature within Windows Update settings to see if you can install the latest build.  If the problem persists, I would drop back to version 1709 for now.  I normally recommend to everyone I work with that they [defer Feature Updates](https://superuser.com/a/1199780/650163) on their Windows 10 machines. I actually have mine configured for `Semi-Annual Channel` with an extra 30-day delay, and I *never* have any problems.

Comment: I just tried checking for updates, there was indeed one update that I didn't have, but it didn't fix the problem. I can't revert back to 1709 because I deleted the backups as my SSD was getting full.

Comment: For future reference, those Windows 10 files and folders that allow you to revert back to the previous version can usually be safely deleted... **after** you confirm that everything is working properly following the upgrade.  Unfortunately, we didn't do that this time.  As a result, you seem to have two potential courses of action:  either tolerate the problem until it is inevitably fixed in a future OS patch, or backup all of your personal files/folders and perform a [clean install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1950-clean-install-windows-10-a.html) with Windows 10 version 1709.

Comment: I deleted those because I had no problems, this problem appeared after I tried to fix a previous one, which was there long before the update. I'll try looking for older graphics drivers and see if that helps.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: Not really, I reverted back to drivers from early 2017 to avoid the stuttering issue, and it'll take a few weeks before I know if the trouble I was trying to avoid by installing the latest drivers still happens using the older driver.

Answer (score 1):

I just got same problem.
I've monitor + TV (on hdmi)
Normally I use only monitor output, with TV output disabled.
I watch a movie on TV
Then changed the TV to anouther input
But forgot to disable HDMI output on PC
And freezes for second every few seconds.
I disabled the HDMI out to TV (tv is on another input now)
and everything is back to normal

Comment: This seems to be a known issue, a few others and I posted on the AMD community forums about it. It was supposed to be fixed in the latest driver release but apparently it isn't. You can follow the discussions here: https://community.amd.com/thread/228886